# Eclipse freezes when adding a breakpoint

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, freeze

When I add a breakpoint, Eclipse freezes for some about 5 seconds. Sometimes it takes much longer until I can continue work, up to one minute. It does not depend on how I set the breakpoint (double-clicking on line numer, or via shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>) or which view is open (Java View, Debug View...) or if Debugging is active.

*Removing* a breakpoint works immediately without any problem.

The problem also only occurs in one workspace. I can't see any entry in the Error Log.

I'm using Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

What could cause this effect?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: @howlger I'm using Neon.3 Release (4.6.3); I added it to the description.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is no longer maintained. Does upgrading to Oxygen.1a fix your issue?

Comment: I still get the issue with Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), but still had the issue. Then I deleted my workspace and set it up newly. The issue dissapeared. My assumption is that there were some corrupted configurations. However, it is solved with a new workspace (that worked for the older Neon version, too).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be due to a bad index file.  I deleted *.index in 
{WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core and this fixes the problem.  Note that by doing this, you're forcing Eclipse to re-index all .java files.  Thus, the first time you go to add an Exception breakpoint, you can expect a wait of several minutes while all classes.

But once all things are settled for the first time, it will become smother.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Linux Ubuntu 16.04 using OpenJDK 1.8 and eclipse v4.15 by installing java-2020-03. Eclipse froze occasionally during debugging but not always. To get around the freezing, I passed the VM argument -Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true. Now I can debug without freezing.